# Selenium WhatsApp Exception "element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, whatsapp, arm64

Using python3 and selenium with chromium to send messages.
Running on ARM64, using fedora33
Below code worked for a while, But stopped working some time 2nd week of July
I haven't changed any software or the program code.
Below is the error I get, Can you help solve it, thanks.

Error Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.101)

Blow is my code snippet (that worked flawless earlier):

```
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + "cookies")

        display = Display(visible=0, size=(1360, 768))
        display.start()

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
        sleep(20)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title = "{}"]'.format(wa_contact)).click()
        sleep(10)

        wa_msg = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        sleep(20)

        # Put the message in one-block
        for i in wa_message_li:
            wa_msg.send_keys(i + Keys.SHIFT + Keys.RETURN)

        wa_msg.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        sleep(15)

        driver.quit()
        display.stop()

      
Tried options like increasing the sleep time and class name, etc. (as suggested in other solutions on similar topic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this error fixed.

It was in the xpath,had the update the below
from:

## driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')

To:

## driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]')

Note: the last "div[2]" was updated to "div[1]"